# AWS CloudFormation fails to create template when it is deployed via CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli

I am setting up the server infrastructure for my application. I am using AWS CloudFormation for that. I am new to the CloudFormation.

I have template.yml with the following code

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: 'AWS CloudFormation Sample Template ElasticBeanstalk_Nodejs_Sample: Configure
  and launch the AWS Elastic Beanstalk sample application. **WARNING** This template
  creates one or more Amazon EC2 instances. You will be billed for the AWS resources
  used if you create a stack from this template.'
Parameters:
  KeyName:
    Description: Name of an existing EC2 KeyPair to enable SSH access to the AWS Elastic
      Beanstalk instance
    Type: AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName
    ConstraintDescription: must be the name of an existing EC2 KeyPair.
Mappings:
  Region2Principal:
    us-east-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    us-west-2:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    us-west-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    eu-west-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    eu-west-2:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    eu-west-3:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-southeast-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-northeast-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-northeast-2:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-northeast-3:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-southeast-2:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-south-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    us-east-2:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ca-central-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    sa-east-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    cn-north-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com.cn
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com.cn
    cn-northwest-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com.cn
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com.cn
    eu-central-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    eu-north-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
Resources:
  WebServerRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - Fn::FindInMap:
                    - Region2Principal
                    - Ref: AWS::Region
                    - EC2Principal
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
      Path: "/"
  WebServerRolePolicy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
    Properties:
      PolicyName: WebServerRole
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            NotAction: iam:*
            Resource: "*"
      Roles:
        - Ref: WebServerRole
  WebServerInstanceProfile:
    Type: AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile
    Properties:
      Path: "/"
      Roles:
        - Ref: WebServerRole
  SampleApplication:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application
    Properties:
      Description: AWS Elastic Beanstalk Sample Node.js Application
  SampleApplicationVersion:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ApplicationVersion
    Properties:
      Description: Version 1.0
      ApplicationName:
        Ref: SampleApplication
      SourceBundle:
        S3Bucket:
          Fn::Join:
            - "-"
            - - elasticbeanstalk-samples
              - Ref: AWS::Region
        S3Key: nodejs-sample.zip
  SampleConfigurationTemplate:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ConfigurationTemplate
    Properties:
      ApplicationName:
        Ref: SampleApplication
      Description: SSH access to Node.JS Application
      SolutionStackName: 64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v4.7.1 running Node.js
      OptionSettings:
        - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
          OptionName: EC2KeyName
          Value:
            Ref: KeyName
        - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
          OptionName: IamInstanceProfile
          Value:
            Ref: WebServerInstanceProfile
  SampleEnvironment:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment
    Properties:
      Description: AWS Elastic Beanstalk Environment running Sample Node.js Application
      ApplicationName:
        Ref: SampleApplication
      TemplateName:
        Ref: SampleConfigurationTemplate
      VersionLabel:
        Ref: SampleApplicationVersion
Outputs:
  URL:
    Description: URL of the AWS Elastic Beanstalk Environment
    Value:
      Fn::Join:
        - ''
        - - http://
          - Fn::GetAtt:
              - SampleEnvironment
              - EndpointURL
```

Then I run the following command to generate the template

```
aws cloudformation package --s3-bucket myan-eat-cloudformation --template-file template.yml --output-template-file template-generated.yaml --profile myan-eat
```

Then I run the following command to deploy it.

```
aws cloudformation deploy --template-file /Users/wai/Desktop/myan-eat/template-generated.yaml --stack-name MyanEat --parameter-overrides KeyName=MyanEat  --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM
```

Then I got the following error.

```
Failed to create/update the stack. Run the following command
to fetch the list of events leading up to the failure
aws cloudformation describe-stack-events --stack-name MyanEat
```

This is what I got when I run the command mentioned

```
{
    "StackEvents": [
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:733553390213:stack/MyanEat/1d01be70-bed0-11ea-a830-068f31eb76a4", 
            "EventId": "8fc77530-bed0-11ea-a830-068f31eb76a4", 
            "ResourceStatus": "ROLLBACK_COMPLETE", 
            "ResourceType": "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack", 
            "Timestamp": "2020-07-05T15:02:36.279Z", 
            "StackName": "MyanEat", 
            "PhysicalResourceId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:733553390213:stack/MyanEat/1d01be70-bed0-11ea-a830-068f31eb76a4", 
            "LogicalResourceId": "MyanEat"
        }, 
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:733553390213:stack/MyanEat/1d01be70-bed0-11ea-a830-068f31eb76a4", 
            "EventId": "SampleApplication-DELETE_COMPLETE-2020-07-05T15:02:35.626Z", 
            "ResourceStatus": "DELETE_COMPLETE", 
            "ResourceType": "AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application", 
            "Timestamp": "2020-07-05T15:02:35.626Z", 
            "StackName": "MyanEat", 
            "ResourceProperties": "{\"Description\":\"AWS Elastic Beanstalk Sample Node.js Application\"}", 
            "PhysicalResourceId": "MyanEat-SampleApplication-1CT11LYW2U9E8", 
            "LogicalResourceId": "SampleApplication"
        }, 
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:733553390213:stack/MyanEat/1d01be70-bed0-11ea-a830-068f31eb76a4", 
            "EventId": "WebServerRole-DELETE_COMPLETE-2020-07-05T15:02:06.914Z", 
            "ResourceStatus": "DELETE_COMPLETE", 
            "ResourceType": "AWS::IAM::Role", 
            "Timestamp": "2020-07-05T15:02:06.914Z", 
            "StackName": "MyanEat", 
            "ResourceProperties": "{\"Path\":\"/\",\"AssumeRolePolicyDocument\":{\"Statement\":[{\"Action\":[\"sts:AssumeRole\"],\"Effect\":\"Allow\",\"Principal\":{\"Service\":[\"ec2.amazonaws.com\"]}}]}}", 
            "PhysicalResourceId": "MyanEat-WebServerRole-FEGUF1UWDY8E", 
            "LogicalResourceId": "WebServerRole"
        }, 
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:733553390213:stack/MyanEat/1d01be70-bed0-11ea-a830-068f31eb76a4", 
            "EventId": "WebServerRole-DELETE_IN_PROGRESS-2020-07-05T15:02:05.736Z", 
            "ResourceStatus": "DELETE_IN_PROGRESS", 
            "ResourceType": "AWS::IAM::Role", 
            "Timestamp": "2020-07-05T15:02:05.736Z", 
            "StackName": "MyanEat", 
            "ResourceProperties": "{\"Path\":\"/\",\"AssumeRolePolicyDocument\":{\"Statement\":[{\"Action\":[\"sts:AssumeRole\"],\"Effect\":\"Allow\",\"Principal\":{\"Service\":[\"ec2.amazonaws.com\"]}}]}}", 
            "PhysicalResourceId": "MyanEat-WebServerRole-FEGUF1UWDY8E", 
            "LogicalResourceId": "WebServerRole"
        }, 
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:733553390213:stack/MyanEat/1d01be70-bed0-11ea-a830-068f31eb76a4", 
            "EventId": "WebServerInstanceProfile-DELETE_COMPLETE-2020-07-05T15:02:05.162Z", 
            "ResourceStatus": "DELETE_COMPLETE", 
            "ResourceType": "AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile", 
            "Timestamp": "2020-07-05T15:02:05.162Z", 
            "StackName": "MyanEat", 
            "ResourceProperties": "{\"Path\":\"/\",\"Roles\":[\"MyanEat-WebServerRole-FEGUF1UWDY8E\"]}", 
            "PhysicalResourceId": "MyanEat-WebServerInstanceProfile-14O10F4FAAL7T", 
            "LogicalResourceId": "WebServerInstanceProfile"
        }, 
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:733553390213:stack/MyanEat/1d01be70-bed0-11ea-a830-068f31eb76a4", 
            "EventId": "SampleApplication-DELETE_IN_PROGRESS-2020-07-05T15:02:04.845Z", 
            "ResourceStatus": "DELETE_IN_PROGRESS", 
            "ResourceType": "AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application", 
            "Timestamp": "2020-07-05T15:02:04.845Z", 
            "StackName": "MyanEat", 
            "ResourceProperties": "{\"Description\":\"AWS Elastic Beanstalk Sample Node.js Application\"}", 
            "PhysicalResourceId": "MyanEat-SampleApplication-1CT11LYW2U9E8", 
            "LogicalResourceId": "SampleApplication"
        }, 
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:733553390213:stack/MyanEat/1d01be70-bed0-11ea-a830-068f31eb76a4", 
            "EventId": "WebServerRolePolicy-DELETE_COMPLETE-2020-07-05T15:02:04.617Z", 
            "ResourceStatus": "DELETE_COMPLETE", 
            "ResourceType": "AWS::IAM::Policy", 
            "Timestamp": "2020-07-05T15:02:04.617Z", 
            "StackName": "MyanEat", 
            "ResourceProperties": "{\"PolicyName\":\"WebServerRole\",\"PolicyDocument\":{\"Statement\":[{\"Resource\":\"*\",\"Effect\":\"Allow\",\"NotAction\":\"iam:*\"}]},\"Roles\":[\"MyanEat-WebServerRole-FEGUF1UWDY8E\"]}", 
            "PhysicalResourceId": "MyanE-WebS-BYWB87MU5AR6", 
            "LogicalResourceId": "WebServerRolePolicy"
        }, 
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:733553390213:stack/MyanEat/1d01be70-bed0-11ea-a830-068f31eb76a4", 
            "EventId": "WebServerInstanceProfile-DELETE_IN_PROGRESS-2020-07-05T15:02:04.505Z", 
            "ResourceStatus": "DELETE_IN_PROGRESS", 
            "ResourceType": "AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile", 
            "Timestamp": "2020-07-05T15:02:04.505Z", 
            "StackName": "MyanEat", 
            "ResourceProperties": "{\"Path\":\"/\",\"Roles\":[\"MyanEat-WebServerRole-FEGUF1UWDY8E\"]}", 
            "PhysicalResourceId": "MyanEat-WebServerInstanceProfile-14O10F4FAAL7T", 
            "LogicalResourceId": "WebServerInstanceProfile"
        }, 
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:733553390213:stack/MyanEat/1d01be70-bed0-11ea-a830-068f31eb76a4", 
            "EventId": "SampleApplicationVersion-DELETE_COMPLETE-2020-07-05T15:02:04.225Z", 
            "ResourceStatus": "DELETE_COMPLETE", 
            "ResourceType": "AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ApplicationVersion", 
            "Timestamp": "2020-07-05T15:02:04.225Z", 
            "StackName": "MyanEat", 
            "ResourceProperties": "{\"Description\":\"Version 1.0\",\"ApplicationName\":\"MyanEat-SampleApplication-1CT11LYW2U9E8\",\"SourceBundle\":{\"S3Bucket\":\"elasticbeanstalk-samples-eu-west-1\",\"S3Key\":\"nodejs-sample.zip\"}}", 
            "PhysicalResourceId": "myaneat-sampleapplicationversion-168k9owspi8bd", 
            "LogicalResourceId": "SampleApplicationVersion"
        }, 
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:733553390213:stack/MyanEat/1d01be70-bed0-11ea-a830-068f31eb76a4", 
            "EventId": "SampleConfigurationTemplate-DELETE_COMPLETE-2020-07-05T15:02:03.820Z", 
            "ResourceStatus": "DELETE_COMPLETE", 
            "ResourceType": "AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ConfigurationTemplate", 
            "Timestamp": "2020-07-05T15:02:03.820Z", 
            "StackName": "MyanEat", 
            "ResourceProperties": "{\"ApplicationName\":\"MyanEat-SampleApplication-1CT11LYW2U9E8\",\"Description\":\"SSH access to Node.JS Application\",\"OptionSettings\":[{\"Value\":\"MyanEat\",\"Namespace\":\"aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration\",\"OptionName\":\"EC2KeyName\"},{\"Value\":\"MyanEat-WebServerInstanceProfile-14O10F4FAAL7T\",\"Namespace\":\"aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration\",\"OptionName\":\"IamInstanceProfile\"}],\"SolutionStackName\":\"64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v4.7.1 running Node.js\"}", 
            "PhysicalResourceId": "", 
            "LogicalResourceId": "SampleConfigurationTemplate"
        }, 
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:733553390213:stack/MyanEat/1d01be70-bed0-11ea-a830-068f31eb76a4", 
            "EventId": "SampleApplicationVersion-DELETE_IN_PROGRESS-2020-07-05T15:02:03.809Z", 
            "ResourceStatus": "DELETE_IN_PROGRESS", 
            "ResourceType": "AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ApplicationVersion", 
            "Timestamp": "2020-07-05T15:02:03.809Z", 
            "StackName": "MyanEat", 
            "ResourceProperties": "{\"Description\":\"Version 1.0\",\"ApplicationName\":\"MyanEat-SampleApplication-1CT11LYW2U9E8\",\"SourceBundle\":{\"S3Bucket\":\"elasticbeanstalk-samples-eu-west-1\",\"S3Key\":\"nodejs-sample.zip\"}}", 
            "PhysicalResourceId": "myaneat-sampleapplicationversion-168k9owspi8bd", 
            "LogicalResourceId": "SampleApplicationVersion"
        }, 
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:733553390213:stack/MyanEat/1d01be70-bed0-11ea-a830-068f31eb76a4", 
            "EventId": "WebServerRolePolicy-DELETE_IN_PROGRESS-2020-07-05T15:02:03.808Z", 
            "ResourceStatus": "DELETE_IN_PROGRESS", 
            "ResourceType": "AWS::IAM::Policy", 
            "Timestamp": "2020-07-05T15:02:03.808Z", 
            "StackName": "MyanEat", 
            "ResourceProperties": "{\"PolicyName\":\"WebServerRole\",\"PolicyDocument\":{\"Statement\":[{\"Resource\":\"*\",\"Effect\":\"Allow\",\"NotAction\":\"iam:*\"}]},\"Roles\":[\"MyanEat-WebServerRole-FEGUF1UWDY8E\"]}", 
            "PhysicalResourceId": "MyanE-WebS-BYWB87MU5AR6", 
            "LogicalResourceId": "WebServerRolePolicy"
        }, 
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:733553390213:stack/MyanEat/1d01be70-bed0-11ea-a830-068f31eb76a4", 
            "EventId": "76b54e50-bed0-11ea-967d-06527026dd82", 
            "ResourceStatus": "ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS", 
            "ResourceType": "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack", 
            "Timestamp": "2020-07-05T15:01:54.217Z", 
            "ResourceStatusReason": "The following resource(s) failed to create: [SampleConfigurationTemplate]. . Rollback requested by user.", 
            "StackName": "MyanEat", 
            "PhysicalResourceId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:733553390213:stack/MyanEat/1d01be70-bed0-11ea-a830-068f31eb76a4", 
            "LogicalResourceId": "MyanEat"
        }, 
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:733553390213:stack/MyanEat/1d01be70-bed0-11ea-a830-068f31eb76a4", 
            "EventId": "SampleConfigurationTemplate-CREATE_FAILED-2020-07-05T15:01:53.497Z", 
            "ResourceStatus": "CREATE_FAILED", 
            "ResourceType": "AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ConfigurationTemplate", 
            "Timestamp": "2020-07-05T15:01:53.497Z", 
            "ResourceStatusReason": "No Solution Stack named '64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v4.7.1 running Node.js' found. (Service: AWSElasticBeanstalk; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValue; Request ID: 7877ee26-c7ef-4b32-8713-056f9263c1d8)", 
            "StackName": "MyanEat", 
            "ResourceProperties": "{\"ApplicationName\":\"MyanEat-SampleApplication-1CT11LYW2U9E8\",\"Description\":\"SSH access to Node.JS Application\",\"OptionSettings\":[{\"Value\":\"MyanEat\",\"Namespace\":\"aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration\",\"OptionName\":\"EC2KeyName\"},{\"Value\":\"MyanEat-WebServerInstanceProfile-14O10F4FAAL7T\",\"Namespace\":\"aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration\",\"OptionName\":\"IamInstanceProfile\"}],\"SolutionStackName\":\"64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v4.7.1 running Node.js\"}", 
            "PhysicalResourceId": "", 
            "LogicalResourceId": "SampleConfigurationTemplate"
        }, 
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:733553390213:stack/MyanEat/1d01be70-bed0-11ea-a830-068f31eb76a4", 
            "EventId": "SampleConfigurationTemplate-CREATE_IN_PROGRESS-2020-07-05T15:01:53.221Z", 
            "ResourceStatus": "CREATE_IN_PROGRESS", 
            "ResourceType": "AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ConfigurationTemplate", 
            "Timestamp": "2020-07-05T15:01:53.221Z", 
            "StackName": "MyanEat", 
            "ResourceProperties": "{\"ApplicationName\":\"MyanEat-SampleApplication-1CT11LYW2U9E8\",\"Description\":\"SSH access to Node.JS Application\",\"OptionSettings\":[{\"Value\":\"MyanEat\",\"Namespace\":\"aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration\",\"OptionName\":\"EC2KeyName\"},{\"Value\":\"MyanEat-WebServerInstanceProfile-14O10F4FAAL7T\",\"Namespace\":\"aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration\",\"OptionName\":\"IamInstanceProfile\"}],\"SolutionStackName\":\"64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v4.7.1 running Node.js\"}", 
            "PhysicalResourceId": "", 
            "LogicalResourceId": "SampleConfigurationTemplate"
        }, 
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:733553390213:stack/MyanEat/1d01be70-bed0-11ea-a830-068f31eb76a4", 
            "EventId": "WebServerInstanceProfile-CREATE_COMPLETE-2020-07-05T15:01:51.611Z", 
            "ResourceStatus": "CREATE_COMPLETE", 
            "ResourceType": "AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile", 
            "Timestamp": "2020-07-05T15:01:51.611Z", 
            "StackName": "MyanEat", 
            "ResourceProperties": "{\"Path\":\"/\",\"Roles\":[\"MyanEat-WebServerRole-FEGUF1UWDY8E\"]}", 
            "PhysicalResourceId": "MyanEat-WebServerInstanceProfile-14O10F4FAAL7T", 
            "LogicalResourceId": "WebServerInstanceProfile"
        }, 
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:733553390213:stack/MyanEat/1d01be70-bed0-11ea-a830-068f31eb76a4", 
            "EventId": "WebServerRolePolicy-CREATE_COMPLETE-2020-07-05T15:00:05.734Z", 
            "ResourceStatus": "CREATE_COMPLETE", 
            "ResourceType": "AWS::IAM::Policy", 
            "Timestamp": "2020-07-05T15:00:05.734Z", 
            "StackName": "MyanEat", 
            "ResourceProperties": "{\"PolicyName\":\"WebServerRole\",\"PolicyDocument\":{\"Statement\":[{\"Resource\":\"*\",\"Effect\":\"Allow\",\"NotAction\":\"iam:*\"}]},\"Roles\":[\"MyanEat-WebServerRole-FEGUF1UWDY8E\"]}", 
            "PhysicalResourceId": "MyanE-WebS-BYWB87MU5AR6", 
            "LogicalResourceId": "WebServerRolePolicy"
        }, 
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:733553390213:stack/MyanEat/1d01be70-bed0-11ea-a830-068f31eb76a4", 
            "EventId": "WebServerRolePolicy-CREATE_IN_PROGRESS-2020-07-05T14:59:51.553Z", 
            "ResourceStatus": "CREATE_IN_PROGRESS", 
            "ResourceType": "AWS::IAM::Policy", 
            "Timestamp": "2020-07-05T14:59:51.553Z", 
            "ResourceStatusReason": "Resource creation Initiated", 
            "StackName": "MyanEat", 
            "ResourceProperties": "{\"PolicyName\":\"WebServerRole\",\"PolicyDocument\":{\"Statement\":[{\"Resource\":\"*\",\"Effect\":\"Allow\",\"NotAction\":\"iam:*\"}]},\"Roles\":[\"MyanEat-WebServerRole-FEGUF1UWDY8E\"]}", 
            "PhysicalResourceId": "MyanE-WebS-BYWB87MU5AR6", 
            "LogicalResourceId": "WebServerRolePolicy"
        }, 
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:733553390213:stack/MyanEat/1d01be70-bed0-11ea-a830-068f31eb76a4", 
            "EventId": "WebServerInstanceProfile-CREATE_IN_PROGRESS-2020-07-05T14:59:51.046Z", 
            "ResourceStatus": "CREATE_IN_PROGRESS", 
            "ResourceType": "AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile", 
            "Timestamp": "2020-07-05T14:59:51.046Z", 
            "ResourceStatusReason": "Resource creation Initiated", 
            "StackName": "MyanEat", 
            "ResourceProperties": "{\"Path\":\"/\",\"Roles\":[\"MyanEat-WebServerRole-FEGUF1UWDY8E\"]}", 
            "PhysicalResourceId": "MyanEat-WebServerInstanceProfile-14O10F4FAAL7T", 
            "LogicalResourceId": "WebServerInstanceProfile"
        }, 
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:733553390213:stack/MyanEat/1d01be70-bed0-11ea-a830-068f31eb76a4", 
            "EventId": "WebServerRolePolicy-CREATE_IN_PROGRESS-2020-07-05T14:59:50.596Z", 
            "ResourceStatus": "CREATE_IN_PROGRESS", 
            "ResourceType": "AWS::IAM::Policy", 
            "Timestamp": "2020-07-05T14:59:50.596Z", 
            "StackName": "MyanEat", 
            "ResourceProperties": "{\"PolicyName\":\"WebServerRole\",\"PolicyDocument\":{\"Statement\":[{\"Resource\":\"*\",\"Effect\":\"Allow\",\"NotAction\":\"iam:*\"}]},\"Roles\":[\"MyanEat-WebServerRole-FEGUF1UWDY8E\"]}", 
            "PhysicalResourceId": "", 
            "LogicalResourceId": "WebServerRolePolicy"
        }, 
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:733553390213:stack/MyanEat/1d01be70-bed0-11ea-a830-068f31eb76a4", 
            "EventId": "WebServerInstanceProfile-CREATE_IN_PROGRESS-2020-07-05T14:59:50.457Z", 
            "ResourceStatus": "CREATE_IN_PROGRESS", 
            "ResourceType": "AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile", 
            "Timestamp": "2020-07-05T14:59:50.457Z", 
            "StackName": "MyanEat", 
            "ResourceProperties": "{\"Path\":\"/\",\"Roles\":[\"MyanEat-WebServerRole-FEGUF1UWDY8E\"]}", 
            "PhysicalResourceId": "", 
            "LogicalResourceId": "WebServerInstanceProfile"
        }, 
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:733553390213:stack/MyanEat/1d01be70-bed0-11ea-a830-068f31eb76a4", 
            "EventId": "WebServerRole-CREATE_COMPLETE-2020-07-05T14:59:48.596Z", 
            "ResourceStatus": "CREATE_COMPLETE", 
            "ResourceType": "AWS::IAM::Role", 
            "Timestamp": "2020-07-05T14:59:48.596Z", 
            "StackName": "MyanEat", 
            "ResourceProperties": "{\"Path\":\"/\",\"AssumeRolePolicyDocument\":{\"Statement\":[{\"Action\":[\"sts:AssumeRole\"],\"Effect\":\"Allow\",\"Principal\":{\"Service\":[\"ec2.amazonaws.com\"]}}]}}", 
            "PhysicalResourceId": "MyanEat-WebServerRole-FEGUF1UWDY8E", 
            "LogicalResourceId": "WebServerRole"
        }, 
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:733553390213:stack/MyanEat/1d01be70-bed0-11ea-a830-068f31eb76a4", 
            "EventId": "SampleApplicationVersion-CREATE_COMPLETE-2020-07-05T14:59:36.690Z", 
            "ResourceStatus": "CREATE_COMPLETE", 
            "ResourceType": "AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ApplicationVersion", 
            "Timestamp": "2020-07-05T14:59:36.690Z", 
            "StackName": "MyanEat", 
            "ResourceProperties": "{\"Description\":\"Version 1.0\",\"ApplicationName\":\"MyanEat-SampleApplication-1CT11LYW2U9E8\",\"SourceBundle\":{\"S3Bucket\":\"elasticbeanstalk-samples-eu-west-1\",\"S3Key\":\"nodejs-sample.zip\"}}", 
            "PhysicalResourceId": "myaneat-sampleapplicationversion-168k9owspi8bd", 
            "LogicalResourceId": "SampleApplicationVersion"
        }, 
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:733553390213:stack/MyanEat/1d01be70-bed0-11ea-a830-068f31eb76a4", 
            "EventId": "SampleApplicationVersion-CREATE_IN_PROGRESS-2020-07-05T14:59:36.536Z", 
            "ResourceStatus": "CREATE_IN_PROGRESS", 
            "ResourceType": "AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ApplicationVersion", 
            "Timestamp": "2020-07-05T14:59:36.536Z", 
            "ResourceStatusReason": "Resource creation Initiated", 
            "StackName": "MyanEat", 
            "ResourceProperties": "{\"Description\":\"Version 1.0\",\"ApplicationName\":\"MyanEat-SampleApplication-1CT11LYW2U9E8\",\"SourceBundle\":{\"S3Bucket\":\"elasticbeanstalk-samples-eu-west-1\",\"S3Key\":\"nodejs-sample.zip\"}}", 
            "PhysicalResourceId": "myaneat-sampleapplicationversion-168k9owspi8bd", 
            "LogicalResourceId": "SampleApplicationVersion"
        }, 
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:733553390213:stack/MyanEat/1d01be70-bed0-11ea-a830-068f31eb76a4", 
            "EventId": "SampleApplicationVersion-CREATE_IN_PROGRESS-2020-07-05T14:59:35.841Z", 
            "ResourceStatus": "CREATE_IN_PROGRESS", 
            "ResourceType": "AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ApplicationVersion", 
            "Timestamp": "2020-07-05T14:59:35.841Z", 
            "StackName": "MyanEat", 
            "ResourceProperties": "{\"Description\":\"Version 1.0\",\"ApplicationName\":\"MyanEat-SampleApplication-1CT11LYW2U9E8\",\"SourceBundle\":{\"S3Bucket\":\"elasticbeanstalk-samples-eu-west-1\",\"S3Key\":\"nodejs-sample.zip\"}}", 
            "PhysicalResourceId": "", 
            "LogicalResourceId": "SampleApplicationVersion"
        }, 
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:733553390213:stack/MyanEat/1d01be70-bed0-11ea-a830-068f31eb76a4", 
            "EventId": "SampleApplication-CREATE_COMPLETE-2020-07-05T14:59:34.066Z", 
            "ResourceStatus": "CREATE_COMPLETE", 
            "ResourceType": "AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application", 
            "Timestamp": "2020-07-05T14:59:34.066Z", 
            "StackName": "MyanEat", 
            "ResourceProperties": "{\"Description\":\"AWS Elastic Beanstalk Sample Node.js Application\"}", 
            "PhysicalResourceId": "MyanEat-SampleApplication-1CT11LYW2U9E8", 
            "LogicalResourceId": "SampleApplication"
        }, 
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:733553390213:stack/MyanEat/1d01be70-bed0-11ea-a830-068f31eb76a4", 
            "EventId": "SampleApplication-CREATE_IN_PROGRESS-2020-07-05T14:59:33.710Z", 
            "ResourceStatus": "CREATE_IN_PROGRESS", 
            "ResourceType": "AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application", 
            "Timestamp": "2020-07-05T14:59:33.710Z", 
            "ResourceStatusReason": "Resource creation Initiated", 
            "StackName": "MyanEat", 
            "ResourceProperties": "{\"Description\":\"AWS Elastic Beanstalk Sample Node.js Application\"}", 
         .........
}
```

What is wrong with my code and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue comes down to this error `No Solution Stack named '64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v4.7.1 running Node.js' found.`.

The [available options](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/platforms/platforms-supported.html#platforms-supported.nodejs) are:

- `64bit Amazon Linux 2 v5.1.0 running Node.js 12`
- `64bit Amazon Linux 2 v5.1.0 running Node.js 10`
- `64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v4.15.0 running Node.js`

Once you've chosen the appropriate one for your application enter its value for the `SolutionStackName` property of the `SampleConfigurationTemplate` resource.

I have updated this to `64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v4.15.0 running Node.js` (which appears the closest to what you're trying to deploy) and can confirm it works with the below template

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: 'AWS CloudFormation Sample Template ElasticBeanstalk_Nodejs_Sample: Configure
  and launch the AWS Elastic Beanstalk sample application. **WARNING** This template
  creates one or more Amazon EC2 instances. You will be billed for the AWS resources
  used if you create a stack from this template.'
Parameters:
  KeyName:
    Description: Name of an existing EC2 KeyPair to enable SSH access to the AWS Elastic
      Beanstalk instance
    Type: AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName
    ConstraintDescription: must be the name of an existing EC2 KeyPair.
Mappings:
  Region2Principal:
    us-east-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    us-west-2:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    us-west-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    eu-west-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    eu-west-2:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    eu-west-3:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-southeast-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-northeast-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-northeast-2:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-northeast-3:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-southeast-2:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-south-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    us-east-2:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ca-central-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    sa-east-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    cn-north-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com.cn
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com.cn
    cn-northwest-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com.cn
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com.cn
    eu-central-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    eu-north-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
Resources:
  WebServerRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - Fn::FindInMap:
                    - Region2Principal
                    - Ref: AWS::Region
                    - EC2Principal
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
      Path: "/"
  WebServerRolePolicy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
    Properties:
      PolicyName: WebServerRole
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            NotAction: iam:*
            Resource: "*"
      Roles:
        - Ref: WebServerRole
  WebServerInstanceProfile:
    Type: AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile
    Properties:
      Path: "/"
      Roles:
        - Ref: WebServerRole
  SampleApplication:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application
    Properties:
      Description: AWS Elastic Beanstalk Sample Node.js Application
  SampleApplicationVersion:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ApplicationVersion
    Properties:
      Description: Version 1.0
      ApplicationName:
        Ref: SampleApplication
      SourceBundle:
        S3Bucket:
          Fn::Join:
            - "-"
            - - elasticbeanstalk-samples
              - Ref: AWS::Region
        S3Key: nodejs-sample.zip
  SampleConfigurationTemplate:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ConfigurationTemplate
    Properties:
      ApplicationName:
        Ref: SampleApplication
      Description: SSH access to Node.JS Application
      SolutionStackName: 64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v4.15.0 running Node.js
      OptionSettings:
        - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
          OptionName: EC2KeyName
          Value:
            Ref: KeyName
        - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
          OptionName: IamInstanceProfile
          Value:
            Ref: WebServerInstanceProfile
  SampleEnvironment:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment
    Properties:
      Description: AWS Elastic Beanstalk Environment running Sample Node.js Application
      ApplicationName:
        Ref: SampleApplication
      TemplateName:
        Ref: SampleConfigurationTemplate
      VersionLabel:
        Ref: SampleApplicationVersion
Outputs:
  URL:
    Description: URL of the AWS Elastic Beanstalk Environment
    Value:
      Fn::Join:
        - ''
        - - http://
          - Fn::GetAtt:
              - SampleEnvironment
              - EndpointURL
```

Comment: No problem, have a great day :)